# 32GB sd card recognised as 2TB

Tags: gparted, sd-card

I am running ubuntu 14.10 , i have a sd card of size 32GB [class 4].When i try to read it in Gparted ,it take immense amount of time and result in showing it as 2TB[2TerraByte].Same goes with `sudo fdisk -l` .Why this behaviour?